# Regex to get last directory and filename from a path

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

So, I have an example path c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt
I want regex to pull folder3\file.txt

I figured this would be everything after

```
1. a slash
2. followed by any number of non slash characters
3. followed by a slash
4. followed by any number of non slash characters
5. followed by a dot 
5.1 that is not (eventually) followed by a slash
```

I've got most of it working

```
\\(?=[^\\]*(?=\\(?=[^\\]*(?=[\.]))))(.*)
```

unless I do this:

c:\folder1\folder2\fol.der3\file.txt  (fol.der3 is the name of the directory)

or this

c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt\ (technically there is no file here)

So, I've got everything except step 5.1

So, I tried adding a negative lookahead after my dot seeking lookahead so it would exclude dots that have a slash somewhere after them:

```
(?=[\.][^\\]*(?![\\]))
```

but that didnt work

Any ideas?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: You can try `[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capturing group instead of using the lookaround and while still making use of the [negative character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
\\([^\\]+\\[^\\.]+\.[^\\.]+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `\\` Match `\`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\\]+\\` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `\` and then match `\`
  - `[^\\.]+\.` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `\` or `.` and then match `\`
  - `[^\\.]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `\` or `.`
- `)` Close group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lpf8no/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$
```

1. `[^\\]+` - matches any character except `\` one or more times
2. `\\` - matches a single `\`
3. `[^\\]+` - matches any character except `\` one or more times
4. `$` - matches the end of string

This is enough to get the last two pieces of your URI.

Whether the last piece is a folder or a file really can't be determined with regex as

- files are not required to have an extension
- URI of a folder does not end with a slash

Unless you can be sure of your input and that proves one of these two points invalid then the regex should be modified accordingly.